# Chicken Broth & soups are spoiling

Tags: canning

I have canned for years. Tomatoes, jams, etc. I startedcanning my own chicken broth and sometimes it spoils or smells terrible after canning, even though it seals. It's usually no ore than a few months old when I try to use it, but am disappointed when I open it and it smells too bad to use. Sometimes it's good, but a lot of times not.why?

Comment: Welcome Robin, without knowing the recipe and process you use for canning, it will be difficult to answer your question.  You can use the edit button to add this information to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's spoiling frequently, you're using an unsafe process. (Maybe boiling water bath, no pressure?) That means you should not eat anything else you've canned with the same process, because it could've become dangerously contaminated without obvious signs.

The only safe way to can low acid foods is with pressure canning. You should *precisely* follow a recipe from a trusted source, like [this meat stock recipe](http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_05/stock_broth.html) from the NCHFP.

Comment: Thank you. I have not been pressure canning it...which is probably the problem.  I have been canning it the same way I can tomatoes...

Comment: @RobinMac - just to emphasize what Jefromi said, please do NOT eat this stuff, even IF it appears to "smell okay."  Pressure canning is essential for low acid foods, and meat stocks/soups are just about the *perfect* medium for bacteria growth.  Canning really isn't something to "improvise" with -- proper recipes are necessary to make foods safe to store at room temp.